Why is my Jetpack Compose TV preview showing a mobile layout instead of TV_720p in Android Studio?
I'm trying to preview my Jetpack Compose layout on a TV device configuration (TV_720p), but despite specifying TV_720p as the device, the preview in Android Studio still looks like a mobile phone. Here’s my setup:
@Preview(device = Devices.TV_720p, uiMode = Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES)
@Composable
internal fun VitrineContentViewEmptyStatePreview() {
    ComposeTvTheme {
     /*My Composable*/
    }
}

In the preview pane on the right, the layout doesn't appear in a TV format but resembles a mobile view instead:

Does anyone know what might be causing this, or if there’s a way to ensure the preview renders correctly as a TV device layout? Any insights would be greatly appreciated!
i also tried TV_1080p but it doesn't make any difference.

Just FYI, showSystemUi = true is necessary if the previewed composable has a fixed size, otherwise preview will take its shape. While the accepted answer will work for fillMaxSize composables, it is not entirely correct.

The Devices constants are a bit whacky, but you can always describe the device's dimensions yourself:
@Preview(
    name = "TV 720p",
    device = "spec:width=1280px,height=720px",
    uiMode = Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES,
)

Which results in this preview:

As Jan Itor suggested in their answer, you can also use device ids, which is more alike what you started with:
@Preview(device = "id:tv_720p")
@Preview(device = "id:tv_1080p")
@Preview(device = "id:tv_4k")


Try adding showSystemUi = true to the @Preview.
Edit:
I checked the value of Devices.TV_720p string and if you copy it directly to your Preview's device argument it shows errors: Unknown parameter: shape, unit. I guess that's why it didn't work. Setting device with preview configuration window results in device = "id:tv_720p" which worked for me. Full code:
@Preview(
    device = "id:tv_720p",
    uiMode = Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES,
    showSystemUi = true,
)

I have to emphasize the importance of showSystemUi param. Let's say we have the following preview:
@Preview(device = "spec:parent=tv_720p")
@Composable
private fun BoxPreview() {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Red).size(100.dp))
}

Which will look like this:

Adding showSystemUi = true will not only add the system bars, but also "ensure the preview renders correctly as a TV device layout":
@Preview(device = "spec:parent=tv_720p", showSystemUi = true)
@Composable
private fun BoxPreview() {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Red).size(100.dp))
}



This only adds the system bar and the action bar which isn't what was asked. On the contrary, that makes the preview look even more phone-like since Android TV doesn't have these bars.

Instead of using showSystemUi you could simply wrap the preview's content in a Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) which will have the same effect, without the additional clutter that showSystemUi adds.
